# SAS - Find and print first non-zero value from a dataset in columns

Tags: arrays, sas

I have a data set with ID in rows and months in columns, as the one shown below.

I want to create an auxiliary column that records the first value that is not zero of each line.

```
ID  M1  M2  M3  M4  M5      Auxiliary column
1   0   0   8   8   7       8
2   7   7   7   .   .       7
3   0   0   0   0   9       9
4   0   9   9   9   8       9
5   1   1   1   1   1       1
6   0   2   2   1   1       2
```

Currently l am using this code, but I haven't been able to get the results I am looking for. Any ideas?

```
data new_ops04;     
set new_ops03;

array MONTHS (24) M1-M24;

RETAIN AUXILIARY_COLUMN 0;
    do i=1 to 24;
    IF MONTHS(i) ne 0 and AUXILIARY_COLUMN = 0 THEN
               AUXILIARY_COLUMN = MONTHS(i);
    end;
        drop i;
run;
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close.  Just drop the retain statement:

```
data new_ops04;     
set new_ops03;

array MONTHS (24) M1-M24;

AUXILIARY_COLUMN = 0;
do i=1 to 24;
IF MONTHS(i) ne 0 and AUXILIARY_COLUMN = 0 THEN
           AUXILIARY_COLUMN = MONTHS(i);
end;
    drop i;
run;
```

you need to consider what happens if the first observation(s) are missing

Answer (score 0):

I would do this use `case` in `proc sql`.  But your problem is that you are not stopping when you reach the first value.  So:

```
flag = 0;
do i=1 to 24 until (flag)
    if MONTHS(i) ne 0 and AUXILIARY_COLUMN = 0 THEN
            AUXILIARY_COLUMN = MONTHS(i);
            flag = 1;
     end;
drop i, flag;
```